# Error Java Jersey: NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, xml, rest, jersey

I'm trying to make a call to a XML file API, but I get this error.

I easily can open the .xml file on the browser by using only the URL.

Can anyone help me, please?

```
private ArrayList<Weather> weatherList = new ArrayList<>();

public String load(String city) {
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
    WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI());
    return target.path("data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&mode=xml&appid=[API_KEY]").request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class);
}

public URI getBaseURI() {
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://api.openweathermap.org").build();
}
```

PS:  Well, I haven't used this:

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(username, password);

client.register(feature);
```

Because the call doesn't need any privileges (no username and password).

Thanks.